# How to get Xpath from nested nodes?

Tags: xpath

how I get this xpath from this xml file

```
<android.widget.ImageView index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Diesel&#10;₱ 58.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 432.000L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,613][683,836]" displayed="true" />
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="720" height="1458">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
              <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                  <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                    <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                      <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                        <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                          <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                            <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,157]" displayed="true">
                              <android.widget.Button index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.Button" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,52][105,157]" displayed="true" />
                              <android.view.View index="1" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Buy Fuel" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[288,83][432,126]" displayed="true" />
                              <android.view.View index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[638,82][683,127]" displayed="true" />
                            </android.view.View>
                            <android.view.View index="1" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,157][720,1405]" displayed="true">
                              <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="true" selected="false" bounds="[0,157][720,1405]" displayed="true">
                                <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Step 1&#10;Select your preferred fuel&#10;Reference Station: &#10;SEAOIL BUNTUN - TUGUEGARAO&#10;￼&#10;￼&#10;￼&#10;Step 2&#10;Enter Amount&#10;LOCQPay Balance&#10;₱ &#10;2,930&#10;.35&#10;Remaining top-up amount&#10;471.657 / 800.000 L&#10;Total liters&#10;0.000 L&#10;Price per Liter&#10;₱ 0.00 / L&#10;Total amount due&#10;₱ 0.00" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,157][720,1405]" displayed="true">
                                  <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[656,365][683,391]" displayed="true" />
                                  <android.view.View index="1" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[81,470][683,575]" displayed="true">
                                    <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Products with this symbol are not available in your Reference Station, but you may still buy them if you plan to redeem elsewhere. Click " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[73,463][677,558]" displayed="true" />
                                    <android.widget.Button index="1" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.Button" text="" content-desc="here" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[321,513][383,556]" displayed="true" />
                                    <android.view.View index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc=" to view the available products per station." resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[73,513][690,583]" displayed="true" />
                                  </android.view.View>
                                  <android.widget.ImageView index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Diesel&#10;₱ 58.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 432.000L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,613][683,836]" displayed="true" />
                                  <android.widget.ImageView index="3" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Gas 91&#10;Regular Unleaded&#10;₱ 61.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 16.778L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,836][683,1059]" displayed="true" />
                                  <android.widget.ImageView index="4" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Gas 95&#10;Premium Unleaded&#10;₱ 62.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 6.919L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,1059][683,1282]" displayed="true" />
                                  <android.widget.ImageView index="5" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Gas 97&#10;Premium Plus Unleaded&#10;₱ 72.84/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 15.960L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,1282][683,1405]" displayed="true" />
                                </android.view.View>
                              </android.view.View>
                            </android.view.View>
                            <android.view.View index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1405][720,1458]" displayed="true">
                              <android.view.View index="0" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Home&#10;Tab 1 of 4" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="true" bounds="[0,1410][180,1458]" displayed="true" />
                              <android.view.View index="1" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="History&#10;Tab 2 of 4" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[180,1410][360,1458]" displayed="true" />
                              <android.view.View index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Scan to Pay&#10;Tab 3 of 4" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,1410][540,1458]" displayed="true" />
                              <android.view.View index="3" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Account&#10;Tab 4 of 4" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[540,1410][720,1458]" displayed="true" />
                            </android.view.View>
                          </android.view.View>
                        </android.view.View>
                      </android.view.View>
                    </android.view.View>
                  </android.view.View>
                </android.view.View>
              </android.view.View>
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
          </android.widget.FrameLayout>
        </android.widget.FrameLayout>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

Get the xpath so I can use it for automation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

- open your browser to the file; by example `file:///tmp/file.xml`
- open (Chrome|Firefox) dev tools
- open 'elements' tab
- search for `58.40` with <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd>
- select the node
- right click on it
- copy as XPath

```
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.ImageView[1]
```

Demo with `xmllint`:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.ImageView[1]' /tmp/file.xml
<android.widget.ImageView index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Diesel&#10;₱ 58.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 432.000L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,613][683,836]" displayed="true"/>
```

Or simpler:

With this Xpath :

```
//*[contains(@content-desc, "58.40")]
```

```
 $ xmllint --xpath '//*[contains(@content-desc, "58.40")]' /tmp/file.xml
```

```
<android.widget.ImageView index="2" package="com.price_locq.mobile" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" content-desc="Diesel&#10;₱ 58.40/Liter&#10;Liter Balance: 432.000L " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[38,613][683,836]" displayed="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that there are an *infinite* number of different XPath expressions which you *could* use to identify that particular element. The correct XPath to choose depends on which of the element's properties you consider crucial.

Since the XML you are querying may change in future, you want to target your XPath query precisely so that it continues to identify the element despite any irrelevant changes. If your XPath identifies the element by features which *aren't* essential, and those features change in future, then your XPath will break.

It's common to see people using XPath expressions which have been generated by browsers and look something like this:

```xml
/foo/bar[2]/baz[1]/quux[6]
```

(i.e. "the 6th `quux` child of the first `baz` child of the second `bar` child of a `foo` root element")
XPaths like these are fragile because a change which introduces an additional `baz` element somewhere in the hierarchy can break the path to the `quux`.

A better approach to identifying an element with an XPath is to decide what it is about the element that makes it the one you want, and then *express those criteria* in XPath syntax.

You haven't actually said what criteria are key, so I will guess that you are after an `ImageView` element, appearing anywhere in the document, which contains the word `Diesel` in its `content-desc` attribute.

```xml
//ImageView[contains(@content-desc, 'Diesel')]
```